# GetModuleHandle from a internal .dll

Tags: delphi, winapi, api, module

i want get the base address from one module, i was tried using GetModuleHandleEx and, works! but, just can i get the base address from the modules: `kernel32.dll` and `user32.dll`, etc...

I really need to get the base address from one of alot modules that has another proces, i mean, get the base address from the module "notepad.exe". I don't know if i have explained nice, hope yes.

best regards;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to call [`EnumProcessModules()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682631%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

The  [`GetModuleHandleEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683200%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  function retrieves a handle for the loaded modules of your application, the `kernel32.dll` and `user32.dll` are *always* present in your app. becausa that work ok for that dlls.

from the MSDN :

> GetModuleHandleEx Retrieves a module handle for the
>   specified module and increments the
>   module's reference count unless
>   GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_UNCHANGED_REFCOUNT
>   is specified. **The module must have
>   been loaded by the calling process.**

Please make you question more clear to help you.

Answer (score 0):

If your ever needing to inspect other processes you should use either dbghelp or toolhelp32, in this case toolhelp32 would be best, using `EnumProcessModules`, msdn has a good example of using it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682621(v=vs.85).aspx